# fadeOut bug/ decrementation implementation

Tags: javascript, html

So for this project, I need to fade out individual elements that include the photo and their corresponding title. However, when I click on the picture, it fades everything out. How can I fix this, so when I click on the photo/photo title, only that element will fade out?

I'm also having trouble decrementing `itemCount.innerHTML = There are ${length} photo(s) being shown`. So when each individual photo is fading out, the length of this will decrement. How can I implement this, so it will work accordingly?

Lastly, I have set up a container to container 4 photos for each row, but it will only contain 2 photos per row. How can I fix this, so it will contain 4 photos for each set of rows?

Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/fengdenn/f4qxywpt/4/

Comment: As for your length problem, you could do something similar to `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img')).filter(el => el.style.opacity !== '0').length` to figure it out. It gets the number of images on the page, filters out the invisible ones, and gives you back the length. A simpler solution for you might be to just keep a running counter of how many you made go invisible, and subtract that from the length. Either way, make sure to update that text during the event listener, not just at page load (otherwise, it'll never change).

Comment: As for your grid problem, it *is* putting 4 elements on one row, just like you asked. If you look at the HTML being outputted, inside your container is a mixture of a lot of images and paragraphs. So a single row contains two images and two paragraphs. I would group one image and one paragraph together into a single div, which would solve a number of problems including this one.

Comment: Thanks, Scotty! I'll go ahead and give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Your fadeOut callback has an event argument, the event object contains the child of #container that was actually clicked.

By adding the event argument to the callback function:

```
function fadeOut(event)
```

Then using this event object to reference the source of the click:

```
let fadeTarget = document.getElementById("container");
```

becomes

```
let fadeTarget = event.target
```

Now you are running the fade function are the specific block. Maybe take a look at the event object that has been output to console for future reference.

I think this will get you want you want. Good luck!

https://jsfiddle.net/z6um1dpv/4/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Much appreciated, luckyape!